# how can i make that line/path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

[image: The image of the code] 
I need to make a line for the bottom of step 3 to step 4.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows}

    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{rect10} = [draw, rectangle, fill = red!25, text width = 8em, text centered, minimum height = 2em]
\tikzstyle{rect11} = [draw, rectangle, fill = red!45, text width = 8em, text centered, minimum height = 2em]
\tikzstyle{rect12} = [draw, rectangle, fill = blue!25, text width = 6em, text centered, minimum height = 3em]
\tikzstyle{rect14} = [draw, rectangle, fill = blue!40, text width = 8em, text centered, minimum height = 3em]
\tikzstyle{rect13} = [draw, rectangle, fill = purple!45, text width = 6em, text centered, minimum height = 4em]
\tikzstyle{diam3} = [draw, diamond, fill = green!30,text width=8em,text badly centered, inner sep=0pt]


\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [rect11] (step1){Initialize
Distances};
   \node [rect10, below of=step1,node distance=2cm] (step2){Initialize 
Dictionary};
   \node [diam3, rounded corners, below of= step2,node distance=3.5cm] (step3){Dijkstra
   (V-1 times)};
      \node [diam4, rounded corners, right of= step3,node distance=4cm] (step4){Update
   Dictionary};
   \path [line] (step1)--(step2);
   \path [line] (step2)--(step3);
   \path [line,rounded corners] (step3)--++(-3,-2) --++(1,1)(step4);;
   \path [line,rounded corners] (step4)--+(-2,2) --(step3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. If you select the code in your question and hit Ctrl + K it will be marked up properly, as you can see from my edit. Your question is a bit unclear though, exactly what kind of line do you want to draw?

Comment: `\path [line,rounded corners] (step3)--++(2,-2) --(step4);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignasi mentioned one possible solution in his comment. Another one, that doesn't depend on the distance between the two nodes, is

```
\path [line] (step3) to[out=-45,in=-135,looseness=2.2] (step4);
\path [line] (step4) to[out=135,in=45,looseness=2.2]   (step3);
```

It doesn't produce exactly the same result, but it's fairly close.

Below I've made a few other modifications to your code as well:

- Change from `\tikzstyle{<stylename>} = [<settings>]` to `\tikzset{<stylename>/.style={<settings>}` for defining styles. There is some discussion about this in [Should `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle` be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372)
  While not documented, `\tikzstyle` works, and will continue to work, so in the end it's up to you which syntax to use.
- Nested styles: you had multiple rectangle styles which were very similar. You can however put one style inside another, so it might make sense to define a basic `rect` style,

  ```
  rect/.style={draw, rectangle, text width = 8em, text centered, minimum height = 2em},
  ```

  and then base the other styles on this, e.g.

  ```
  rect10/.style={rect, fill = red!25},
  ```
- Make use of the `positioning` library. With that library you write `<position>=of <othernode>` instead of `<position> of=<othernode>`. The latter syntax, which you used, is actually deprecated (see [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)).

  With the code as below, the distance is measured between the borders of the nodes, so you don't have to specify a different `node distance` in each case.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains}

\tikzset{
    line/.style={draw, -latex'},
    rect/.style={draw, rectangle, text width = 8em, text centered, minimum height = 2em},
    diam/.style={draw, diamond, rounded corners, text width=8em,text badly centered, inner sep=0pt},
    rect10/.style={rect, fill = red!25},
    rect11/.style={rect, fill = red!45},
    rect12/.style={rect, fill = blue!25, text width = 6em},
    rect14/.style={rect, fill = blue!40},
    rect13/.style={rect, fill = purple!45, text width = 6em},
    diam3/.style={diam, fill = green!30},
    diam4/.style={diam, fill = blue!30}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [rect11]                 (step1) {Initialize Distances};
   \node [rect10, below=of step1] (step2) {Initialize Dictionary};
   \node [diam3,  below=of step2] (step3) {Dijkstra (V-1 times)};
   \node [diam4,  right=of step3] (step4) {Update Dictionary};
   \path [line] (step1) -- (step2);
   \path [line] (step2) -- (step3);
   \path [line] (step3) to[out=-45,in=-135,looseness=2.2] (step4);
   \path [line] (step4) to[out=135,in=45,looseness=2.2]   (step3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```